# Raw Image display on screen

Tags: windows-phone-7

My video file is in .raw file and i wan read it frame by frame using bitmap method.But my video size too big is around 1.6gb.So What can i do to it in order to display in on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transcode your video into a more suitable format for the phone, MP4 for example. You can transcode with software such as [VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode).